# htmlspecialchars ampersand

Tags: php, magento, character-encoding, htmlspecialchars

```
<h3><?php echo $this->__('Details & Documents') ?></h3>
```

The above prints out as: `Details &amp; Documents`

What is the proper syntax so that it prints as: `Details & Documents`?

Thanks

Comment: This prints fine for me... are you changing `&` in the method `$this->__();`?

Comment: Based on the `<h3>`-tag, `Details &amp; Documents` *is* the correct output from the function. You're not allowed to have stray ampersands in HTML (or XML, for that matter); that's why `&amp;` is used instead.

Comment: `Details &amp; Documents` is _correct_.

Comment: @MichaelMadsen &amp; prints as &amp; unfortunately.

Comment: @SLaks Unfortunately <pre><h3><?php echo $this->__('Details &amp; Documents') ?></h3></pre> prints as Details &amp; Documents, and not Details & Documents.

Comment: @vulgarbulgar: `Details & Documents` is invalid HTML.

Comment: @vulgarbulgar: Then my guess is that you either: a) have something else re-encoding the HTML, b) actually have `Details &amp; Documents` as the input, or c) you're not viewing it as HTML/XML. In any case, it seems like there's something missing here.

Answer (score 5):

[html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) should do what you want:

```
<h3><?php echo html_entity_decode($this->__('Details & Documents')) ?></h3>
```

Although there may be a Magento-specific setting for this.

Comment: Same, pritns as Details &amp; Documents

Comment: I noticed that before Tim Cooper had edited your post, there was a space after `&`, so it looked like this: `& amp;`. Was that a typo, or does your output _actually_ look like that?

Comment: That was on purpose, because, for whatever reason, whenever I entered without the space, the post here on this website would print as an '&', instead of &amp;